# Get the latitude and longitude from the user ip

Tags: 7, javascript, google-maps

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude from the user who connected to my website to draw or show his position on a map, but it showed him in the wrong postion. Is there any way to get the accurate latitude and longitude?

```
    <?php drupal_add_js('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'); ?>
     `<script type="text/javascript">
        //document.write("Hello World!");
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            function initialize(att,lon,title) {

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(att,lon),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //TERRAIN
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"),mapOptions);
            map.disableDefaultUI = true;

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon:Drupal.settings.basePath+'themes/bartik/logo.png',
                position: map.getCenter()
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infowindow.setContent('<div class="title-map">'+title+'</div>');
            jQuery('.title-map').parent().removeAttr('style');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

                infowindow.open(map, marker);

            });
        }
        jQuery.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
            initialize(data.latitude,data.longitude,'title');
        });
    </script>
    <?php

     echo "<div id="map_canvas2" style="width:605px; height:465px"></div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting an IP to a latitude and longitude isn't a good idea since the user could be using a proxy. A better way would be to use HTML5 geolocation, which tries to get a location based on a couple of parameters: IP, wireless connection, cell tower location, GPS ...

Try:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);

function show_map(position) {
  initialize(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'title');
}
```

More info on HTML5 geolocation [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html), make sure you have a fallback in case the browser doesn't support geolocation or the user declines your request to share his/her location (graceful degradation).

Comment: Hm, da-wist-ik-nie ... oeps, hier spreekt men geen NL (of toch)?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation I currently use I've seen in a couple other questions, but I haven't seen it as the selected answer.

**It is explained detailed in blog [thenullreference.com](http://thenullreference.com/blog/quick-and-reliable-way-to-get-location-information-about-your-users/), but here it is in short:**

---

Essentially all you need to do is load Google's API loader script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http(s)://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Then you have access to several properties that give you detailed location info.

The object you want to look at is **google.loader.ClientLocation**

- ClientLocation.latitude
- ClientLocation.longitude
- ClientLocation.address.city
- ClientLocation.address.country
- ClientLocation.address.country_code - ISO 3166-1 country code
- ClientLocation.address.region - country specific region in US this is state

*Note some of these can be null

For more info on this API check out [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/)

Does anyone else use this?  Does anyone have something that they use that is as simple and better? Are there issues with this approach?

I'm unaware of the coverage/accuracy of this solution, but I would think that Google keeps it updated and is probably pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

My app requires certain functionality to be enabled when location changes, so I needed to not rely on HTML5 implementations of getting the user location.  I found www.telize.com as well as www.iptolatlng.com to be helpful what I'm doing bc they return JSON results.

Comment: Can you summarize how you used these two services with Drupal?